# Difficulty to normalize CSV archive in encog in JAVA

Tags: java, csv, neural-network, normalization, encog

I'm trying to normalize this file to use in neural network training, it's in comma-separated CSV format and was created using Excel.

[image: Archive]

To normalize the file, I'm trying to use this code

```
    File archiveNotNormalized = new File("Arch1.csv");
    File archiveNormalized = new File("Arch2.csv");

    EncogAnalyst analyst = new EncogAnalyst();
    AnalystWizard wizard = new AnalystWizard(analyst);

    wizard.wizard(ArchiveNotNormalized, true, AnalystFileFormat.DECCOMMA_SEMI);

    final AnalystNormalizeCSV norm = new AnalystNormalizeCSV();
    norm.analyze(ArchiveNotNormalized, false, CSVFormat.DECIMAL_COMMA, analyst);
    norm.setProduceOutputHeaders(true);

    norm.normalize(ArchiveNormalized);
```

When the code runs with only this wrong result:

[image: Error]

Can someone help?

Comment: First of all, what do you mean by normalize?

Comment: The data will be used in the training of a neural network, so that I can use this data in training they must be between 1 and -1. With normalize I mean put the values of the file in the range between 1 and -1.

Comment: Try to change from *DECCOMMA_SEMI* to *DECPNT_COMMA* in the line wizard.wizard? No idea on what format CSV you are using but i guess is comma seperated

Comment: As I said the format is separated by commas, the columns are sepradas by semicolon.